# Usage condition (WHERE) in window function (LEAD) after accumulating values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of records of usage of certain resources. Every day the logs are updated showing the views that the resources had for the next 30 days. When a user enters the system, he informs when he will use the chosen resource, thus counting a view for the selected date.

My source table:

| ID | Views | Aquisition | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 02 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 |
| 01 | 04 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-16 |
| 01 | 02 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-17 |
| 01 | 08 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-18 |
| 01 | 11 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-19 |
| 01 | 09 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-20 |
| 01 | 05 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-16 |
| 01 | 02 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-17 |
| 01 | 09 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-18 |
| 01 | 11 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-19 |
| 01 | 10 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-20 |
| 01 | 10 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-21 |

The table above shows a summary containing two acquisition dates for the same resource with id=01. For each acquisition date, the views for the next 6 days (counting the current day) are checked.

I perform a SUM operation of views by acquisition date and after a LEAD operation, returning:

| ID | Views | Views_LEAD | Aquisition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 47 | 36 | 2022-02-16 |
| 01 | 36 | null | 2022-02-15 |

However, I need that the return value displayed in the "views_lead" column is not exactly the sum of all the values in the previous row, but only the values whose dates ("date") match.

For example, the date "2022-02-15" has no match for rows whose "Acquisition date = 2022-02-16". So your view value (2) must not be counted, and the value to be displayed in the "views_lead" column must be equal to 34.

Expected outcome:

| ID | Views | Views_LEAD | Aquisition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 47 | 34 | 2022-02-16 |
| 01 | 36 | null | 2022-02-15 |

My attempt includes the Window operation, but I don't know how to apply this condition to apply the sum.

```
SELECT 
t1.id,
DATE(t1.aquisition) as aquisition_date,
SUM(t1.views) as views,
LEAD(SUM(views),1) over(PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY 
DATE(t1.aquisition) DESC) as views_lead
FROM 
table_views t1  
GROUP BY 
t1.id,
DATE(t1.aquisition)
ORDER BY
DATE(t1.aquisition) DESC
```

[DBIFFDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3bb7dee73c55a02a348f4782987d377f)

Comment: Can you explain more about the last piece of your question (I do mean this part: "For example.......34 ")

Comment: create a fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) with the sample data and update your post with the URL.

Comment: [DBIFFDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3bb7dee73c55a02a348f4782987d377f)

Comment: @Luuk
The Views column must contain a cumulative sum for each acquisition data. However, when performing the LEAD, column (views_lead) operation, I only need to consider the sum of the views that have corresponding dates for each acquisition.
The day 2022-02-15 does not exist for the acquisition = 2022-02-16 and its value (value of the 1st line, views=2) must not be added to the Sum, causing instead of a simple LEAD that would return 36 , return 34.

Comment: Please, do NOT ask for an explanation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e89983b8e1f4af3dc7787482975bbd4c   

Comment: I tried to make it a bit more clear with this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1713853ca8b7ae72f7d05c313eeeeaa7), In "part 2" you see the 34 which you want to see, which is the sum of the values for date '2022-02-15' that also have a previous 15th.  That's why we need again a LEAD on the 3rd part.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt. When applying the query to the entire database, the results did not come out as expected, probably some part of the logic breaks for some reason, but I don't have enough knowledge to identify the problem. I thought the solution would be simpler and more trivial.

Comment: it may be best to run a sub-query per row `(select sum(views) from table_views where id = t1.id and aquisition < t1.aquisition and  aquisition + interval '6 day' <= t1.aquisition) as views_lead` I try to avoid sub-queries in the select but sometimes they are the best solution.

Comment: @Luuk Would you be able to put your solution in an answer? There are lots of questions answered in the comments and it's complicated to comprend le solution il bits and pièces. Maybe I should raise the subjet on Meta if there isn't an active post about it?

Comment: @Kendle: I did also comment "Please, do NOT ask for an explanation"    It's mainly because I do not know anymore what I answered more than 5 weeks ago.  When the problem was clearer, and the solution was better, I would have posted it as an answer, but for this case I will pass.....

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version                                                                                                |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | PostgreSQL 14.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-4), 64-bit |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_views (
>
> ID INT,   Views INT,  Aquisition DATE,    "Date" Date);
>
> INSERT INTO table_views VALUES
> (01   ,02 ,'2022-02-15',  '2022-02-15'),
> (01   ,04 ,'2022-02-15',  '2022-02-16'),
> (01   ,02 ,'2022-02-15',  '2022-02-17'),
> (01   ,08 ,'2022-02-15',  '2022-02-18'),
> (01   ,11 ,'2022-02-15',  '2022-02-19'),
> (01   ,09 ,'2022-02-15',  '2022-02-20'),
> (01   ,05 ,'2022-02-16',  '2022-02-16'),
> (01   ,02 ,'2022-02-16',  '2022-02-17'),
> (01   ,09 ,'2022-02-16',  '2022-02-18'),
> (01   ,11 ,'2022-02-16',  '2022-02-19'),
> (01   ,10 ,'2022-02-16',  '2022-02-20'),
> (01   ,10 ,'2022-02-16',  '2022-02-21');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

12 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT 
> t1.id,
> DATE(t1.aquisition) as aquisition_date,
> SUM(t1.views) as views,
> LEAD(SUM(views),1) over(PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY 
> DATE(t1.aquisition) DESC) as views_lead
> FROM 
> table_views t1  
> GROUP BY 
> t1.id,
> DATE(t1.aquisition)
> ORDER BY
> DATE(t1.aquisition) DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | aquisition_date | views | views_lead
> -: | :-------------- | ----: | ---------:
>  1 | 2022-02-16      |    47 |         36
>  1 | 2022-02-15      |    36 |       null
> ```

> ```
> select
>   ID,
>   aquisition_date,
>   views,
>   LEAD(view_lead) OVER (ORDER BY aquisition_date DESC)
> FROM (
> SELECT
>   ID,
>   aquisition_date,
>   SUM(views) as views,
>   SUM(views_lead) as view_lead
> FROM (
>   SELECT 
>     t1.id,
>     DATE(t1.aquisition) as aquisition_date,
>     (t1.views) as views,
>     LEAD((views),1) over(PARTITION BY t1.id,DATE(t1.aquisition) ORDER BY DATE(t1.aquisition) DESC) as views_lead
>   FROM 
>   table_views t1  
>   ORDER BY
>     id, DATE(t1.aquisition) DESC
> ) x
> GROUP BY
>    ID,
>    aquisition_date
> ORDER BY
>     ID,
>    aquisition_date DESC
>    )y
> ```
>
> ```
> id | aquisition_date | views | lead
> -: | :-------------- | ----: | ---:
>  1 | 2022-02-16      |    47 |   34
>  1 | 2022-02-15      |    36 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e89983b8e1f4af3dc7787482975bbd4c)*